# How to install firefoxdriver webdriver for python3 selenium on ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, selenium, ubuntu

I installed python3-selenium apt package on Ubuntu 16.04. While installing, got a message:

```
Suggested packages:
  chromedriver firefoxdriver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-selenium
```

When I try to run test cases in python3-django, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/firefoxdriver/webdriver.xpi'
```

I did searching for packages name firefoxdriver in Ubuntu repositories but none exist.

Any help with installing the webdrivers appreciated.

Comment: You might consider asking on http://askubuntu.com or http://superuser.com but as far as I can tell this has nothing to do with programming, and doesn't even seem relevant to `selenium` (or python or django)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to install the Firefox webdriver after installing the `python3-selenium` package.

You could install using pip instead, ideally in a virtual environment.

If you have Firefox installed and you run `pip install selenium` in your virtual environment, you should be good to go.

Comment: I installed selenium via ubuntu python3-selenium package. Is there any way to install the firefox webdriver for this? Or, are you suggesting to install via pip instead?

Comment: Worked for me too. Small remark  : for python3 use `pip3` .

Comment: @jadsq you only need pip3 if you are installing globally. If you are inside a Python 3 virtual environment, then `pip` will work fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with virtualenv, thanks for the precision.