# webdriver.xpi not found - Python3, Linux Mint

Tags: linux, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I am new to the forum but have searched the posts for something to fix my problem.

Here are the posts I've used to attempt troubleshooting:
[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058302/missing-file-in-compiled-selenium-app)
[#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148860/how-to-install-firefoxdriver-webdriver-for-python3-selenium-on-ubuntu)
~And other Google results.

I switched to Linux Mint from Windows and I am having trouble getting set up.  I am also new to Python/programming in general, so bear with me.

Linux Mint comes with Python2 installed but I have done all of my practice with Python3, so I have installed Python 3 which means I also had to install the Python3 versions of Selenium, Geckodriver, etc. in order to run my practice scripts for webscraping.

When I run my code, it prompts for a search term as I intended, but then it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myName/Documents/Programming Misc/Python/craigslistSearch_linkGeneration_v02.py", line 15, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.profile.add_extension()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 91, in add_extension
    self._install_extension(extension)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 251, in _install_extension
    compressed_file = zipfile.ZipFile(addon, 'r')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1009, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/firefoxdriver/webdriver.xpi'
```

Here's the offending code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  #To launch the browser (Firefox)
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #To be able to send special keys (i.e., DOWN, UP, RIGHT, LEFT, TAB, HOME, etc.)
import time #To pause the program for x seconds
import string #To run string.replace()
import requests

#prompt the user to enter their desired search term
print('Please enter your search term')
searchTerm = input()
newSearchTerm = str.replace(searchTerm, ' ', '+')



#open browser and navigate to craigslist + user-defined search term(s)
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
searchURL = browser.get('https://seattle.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=' + newSearchTerm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you install old Selenium for Python 3,  because `webdriver.xpi` is legacy webdriver for firefox browser, it's replaced by `geckodriver`.

Please show the version of Selenium, geckodriver and other related stuff you installed.

If you use Selenium 2, it will try to find `webdriver.xpi`, since Selenium 3, it will try to find `geckodriver`, so give a try to install Selenium 3 or heigher.

Comment: Sorry I hit Enter but didn't finish typing

Here's GeckoDriver
~ $ geckodriver --version
    geckodriver 0.11.1 


I don't know why I can't find any of these things.  I know for a fact that Selenium was working when I was using Python2
me@me-Linux ~ $ ActivePython --version
ActivePython: command not found
me@me-Linux ~ $ activepython --version
activepython: command not found
me@me-Linux ~ $ activepython -version
activepython: command not found
me@me-Linux ~ $ requests -version
requests: command not found
me@me-Linux ~ $ selenium --version
selenium: command not found

Comment: what version of Selenium for python you installed?

Comment: i apologize - I will try to re-format my response above after work today so that it is easier to read.  To answer your question, I am not sure what version of selenium I have.  I know I have SOME version because it worked on Python 2.x — is it worth me uninstalling Python2 and its dependencies?  Will that simplify things and cause fewer issues?

Comment: SOLVED: I downloaded the "Python Wheel" version of Selenium and it seems to have worked.  I had originally downloaded the Source tar ball.

Here is where I went: (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads)